# Convert a Double Array to UIImage in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, string, swift, image-processing

Is it possible to convert a double array to UIImage using UIImage function?

```
var ImageDouble = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0]
```

UIImage function asks for String. I tried converting the array on individual element to strings and the whole thing to string, I get a nill result. Can someone help?

[Edit:]

As it seems I was not really clear on my problem. To make it more clear, I am developing a software which crops numbers & operators from a mathematical expression and shows me all the chunks one by one. Now, how do I go about it in Swift? :

Step-1: I have a grayscale image provided. I read it using UIImage function. I convert it to a custom RGBA function as follows so that I can deal on a pixel level like we do in MATLAB or Python or C++. The function is inspired from many websites's suggestions to use it.

```
struct Pixel {
var value: UInt32
var red: UInt8 {
    get { return UInt8(value & 0xFF) }
    set { value = UInt32(newValue) | (value & 0xFFFFFF00) }
}
var green: UInt8 {
    get { return UInt8((value >> 8) & 0xFF) }
    set { value = (UInt32(newValue) << 8) | (value & 0xFFFF00FF) }
}
var blue: UInt8 {
    get { return UInt8((value >> 16) & 0xFF) }
    set { value = (UInt32(newValue) << 16) | (value & 0xFF00FFFF) }
}
var alpha: UInt8 {
    get { return UInt8((value >> 24) & 0xFF) }
    set { value = (UInt32(newValue) << 24) | (value & 0x00FFFFFF) }
}
```

}

```
struct RGBA {
var pixels: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Pixel>
var width: Int
var height: Int
init?(image: UIImage) {
    guard let cgImage = image.CGImage else { return nil }
    width = Int(image.size.width)
    height = Int(image.size.height)
    let bitsPerComponent = 8
    let bytesPerPixel = 4
    let bytesPerRow = width * bytesPerPixel
    let imageData = UnsafeMutablePointer<Pixel>.alloc(width * height)
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    var bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Big.rawValue
    bitmapInfo |= CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue & CGBitmapInfo.AlphaInfoMask.rawValue
    guard let imageContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(imageData, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo) else { return nil }
    CGContextDrawImage(imageContext, CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: image.size), cgImage)
    pixels = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Pixel>(start: imageData, count: width * height)
}

func toUIImage() -> UIImage? {
    let bitsPerComponent = 8
    let bytesPerPixel = 4
    let bytesPerRow = width * bytesPerPixel
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    var bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Big.rawValue
    bitmapInfo |= CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue & CGBitmapInfo.AlphaInfoMask.rawValue
    let imageContext = CGBitmapContextCreateWithData(pixels.baseAddress, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo, nil, nil)
    guard let cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(imageContext) else {return nil}
    let image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)
    return image
}
```

}

Step-2: Now I take one channel of the image [Red: it does not matter which one I take, since all the channels have same output] and apply my custom median filter of kernel size 5x5.

Step-3: Next, I do the binarization of the image using Nibblack approximation,where I used averaging filter and standard deviation.

Step-4: After that, I used connected component labelling to separate out different connected components of the image.

Step-5: Finally, I need to crop the labelled images and resize it. For cropping from the original image , I know the location by using a smart location algorithm. For resizing, I want to use Core Graphics Resizing filter. However, for that I need to convert my current output [a two-dimensional array or flattened] to UIImage or CGImage.

**That's my real question: How do I convert to UIImage or CGImage from two-dimensional array or flattened array which are of type `Array<Double>` or `Array<Int>`?**

Comment: why are you using double for image?

Comment: Because at times, the calculation we do on images after applying averaging filter gives a result in Double. I can deal with Int as well. The point is to convert it to UIImage.

Comment: Can you describe us what you really want to achieve? I am smelling a [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem here.

Comment: That could be a possibility! For that I apologize! However, the thing I am trying to achieve is: I want to be able to convert to one of the Swift's existing image type (UIImage or CGImage) so that I can use CG Filters. But I have an array with Double data type , where the array is definitely flattened from the original image which is a 2D array.

Comment: Can you post a real example of the array? How large an array are we talking about here? Maybe some code on how you get the array.

Comment: Ok I now see what you are trying to do. You have an array of values from which you want to build an image. What is the range of values, 0...255? Is it a single channel or multiple? If it is multiple then how are they laid out in the array, interleaved or sequential, and is there an alpha channel? What are the final dimensions of the image?

Comment: The other thing is why are you working on four channels when you start with a greyscale image? It seems like you could just work on one and save a lot of resources.

Comment: My image is a grayscale. It's one channel. Three channels are used to read the RGB values from the color image and for grayscale all the R,G,B values are same, which gives you a grayscale image. Yes, you are right on dealing with one channel and that's what I do. Alpha channel is not important. Values are ranging between 0 and 255. They are in double array and can be converted to UInt8 by typecasting. Final dimensions are dynamic and changes from image to image. The most common one is 120x90. They are row major ordered array and sequential.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var ImageDouble = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0]
let images = ImageDouble.map{ UIImage(named: "\($0)")}
```

the map function will transform your array to another array.

Comment: I tried this. I got an array, which is right; but the array is nill.

Comment: Have your image assets contain images name 1.0.png, 2.0.png...?

Comment: No. this is just a double array created like we would do in MATLAB matrix or python array. I want to convert it to UIImage or CGImage(if possible), so that I can view it or may be use in future.

Comment: I think it would create an image array if you have some image in your image assets, if not, the image array would be nil.

Answer (score -1):

Just try this:

```
var str:[String] = [];

for (var i=0;i<ImageDouble.count;i++){
   str.append(String(ImageDouble[i]));
}
print(str)
```

But why would you pass a String of numbers to an UIImage? Are images in your asset named as numbers?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you want to render 1, 2, etc into a bitmap.

First you need a function to do that, and then use flatMap on the array of doubles using this. This will ensure you get an array of UIImages in a safe way by filtering if any nil results when we try to create images.

```
func createNumberImage(number:Double) -> UIImage?{

    //Set a frame that you want.
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
    let view = UIView(frame:frame )
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    let label = UILabel(frame:frame)
    view.addSubview(label)

    label.font  = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(100);
    label.text = String(format: "%.1lf", arguments:[number])
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    view

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);
    view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return screenShot
}

let doubles = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0]

//Get the array of UIImage objects.  
let images = doubles.flatMap { createNumberImage($0) }
```

You can use playground to verify this working.  Also you might want to set proper background and text colors and font size to suite your requirements.

Comment: Hi there, I only want to create the bitmap except for putting a number. I want to put the values in the array of double to create a image.

Comment: My code generates bitmaps  where each one of it actually draws the number. I am not sure if you want one single image that displays all numbers in it, or an image each for each number. My solution creates the later.

Comment: I don't want numbers to be displayed. Rather I want to convert a 3x3 matrix or the flattened matrix into an image. The values for the image will lie between 0-255.